# Customize text annotations of heatmaps in a Seaborn FacetGrid to be in EngFormatter style

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

While I am trying to produce a heatmap compare the performance of different user segments across time periods, I cannot customize the annotation of the heatmaps in EngFormatter style (i.e. 1233 = 1k, 10000 = 10k, 2000000 = 2M, etc.). I could not find where is the location of the annotation text element under each heatmap within the FacetGrid.

How to customize the unit of Facegrid Annotation?

My effort:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def draw_heatmap(*args, **kwargs):
    data = kwargs.pop('data')
    d = data.pivot(index=args[1], columns=args[0], values=args[2])
    sns.heatmap(d, **kwargs)

fg = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='time_interval',height=6)
fg.map_dataframe(
    draw_heatmap,
    'user_action', 'segment', 'users',
    cbar=True, cmap="Blues", square = True, annot=True,fmt='.2g'
)

from matplotlib.ticker import EngFormatter
for t in fg.texts: t.set_text(EngFormatter(t.get_text()))
```

Current output:

[image]

Desired output:

A visualization like above but where the displayed text annotations of heatmaps are in EngFormatter style

Sample dataset:

```
index,time_interval,user_action,segment,users
0,time_2,,Super Heavy,1233
1,time_1,Click Use,Medium,10000
2,time_1,Click View Detail,Light,2000000
3,time_2,Click View Detail,Medium,3999
4,time_1,Click See All,Medium,14542
```

Session info:

```
polars==0.17.3
pandas==1.5.3
seaborn==0.12.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close to getting it right, but put the iteration and EngFormatter alteration of the `texts` attribute of the `Axes` object *within* the `draw_heatmap` function. You also need to capture the `Axes` of the seaborn heatmap plots themselves to modify their annotations (i.e., not the `texts` attribute of the FacetGrid, but of the heatmaps within the grid).

E.g., using your provided sample data (slightly modified for extended demonstration):

```py
import itertools as itl
import random

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

from matplotlib.ticker import EngFormatter

times = ["time_1", "time_2"]
user_actions = ["Click See All", "Click Use", "Click View Detail"]
segments = ["Light", "Medium", "Heavy"]

all_combos = list(map(list, list(itl.product(times, user_actions, segments))))

cols = ["time_interval", "user_action", "segment", "users"]

data = [c + [random.randint(1, int(2e6))] for c in all_combos]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)


def draw_heatmap(*args, **kwargs):
    data = kwargs.pop("data")
    d = data.pivot(index=args[1], columns=args[0], values=args[2])
    ax = sns.heatmap(d, **kwargs)

    # Make annotations of heatmaps in EngFormatter style
    for text in ax.texts:
        text.set_text(
            EngFormatter()(float(text.get_text()))
        )


fg = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="time_interval", height=6)
fg.map_dataframe(
    draw_heatmap,
    "user_action",
    "segment",
    "users",
    cbar=True,
    cmap="Blues",
    square=True,
    annot=True,
    fmt=".2g",
)

plt.show()
```

produces:
[image: EngFormatter text annotated seaborn facet grid heatmaps]

where the randomly generated data ('`df`') shown above was:

```
   time_interval        user_action segment    users
0         time_1      Click See All   Light   744670
1         time_1      Click See All  Medium   150098
2         time_1      Click See All   Heavy   588170
3         time_1          Click Use   Light  1811019
4         time_1          Click Use  Medium   495390
5         time_1          Click Use   Heavy  1312397
6         time_1  Click View Detail   Light  1598512
7         time_1  Click View Detail  Medium  1763711
8         time_1  Click View Detail   Heavy   930745
9         time_2      Click See All   Light  1832730
10        time_2      Click See All  Medium  1868217
11        time_2      Click See All   Heavy     4131
12        time_2          Click Use   Light  1163743
13        time_2          Click Use  Medium   600851
14        time_2          Click Use   Heavy  1019326
15        time_2  Click View Detail   Light  1527671
16        time_2  Click View Detail  Medium   559187
17        time_2  Click View Detail   Heavy  1943017
```

Comment: Thanks, John, this is exactly what I expect. Well I guess I should spend more effort in learning the structure of matplotlib first haha

Comment:  It was a good question and after all that's what this site was/is meant for. Matplotlib is very complex; I learned more about its structure in looking into this problem, too! Seaborn is nice in that its API is less overwhelming. But both are great Python visualization tools ☮️ ✌️